# How to get the complete list of hexadecimal color numbers using a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, hex

I haven't done much research I must confess, but help is always welcome. This is the code I have but it's not complete because of my laziness caused by stackoverflows tremendous usefulness. The complete list should have at least 3 million colors.

```
<script>
    var i=0;
    document.write("arrayColor=[");
    for(var i=10;i<99;i++){
      for(var j=10;j<99;j++){
        document.write("\"#"+j+""+""+j+""+i+"\""+",")
      }
    };
    document.write("]");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one loop and `toString(16)` function to get hex representation of number:

```
<script>
    var colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
        colors.push("#" + ("000000" + i.toString(16)).slice(-6));
    }
    document.write(JSON.stringify(colors));
</script>
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/24mmQ/) (`document.write` changed to `console.log` and only 300 colors)

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSON do you know any online editor I can check your code at, or do you have a sample link?

Comment: @user2887761 i've added fiddle(open console to check result list)

Comment: Way too heavy, but it works. I made the mistake in my pc at first, now I figured it's heavy but works.

Comment: @user2887761 what you mean by 'heavy'? it is very light actually ;)

Comment: By view it in the browser it's a nightmare, but adding it inside some code might be as light as feather, can you help me with that?

Comment: @user2887761 you can post this js code (with document.write) in browser console (in chrome for example), run it and save result in file...

Comment: What I want to know is something really simple, how to remove "[ ]" out of the color array, so I can add an array[color].

Comment: I got it now, var arrayColor=color;call by arrayColor[0]; thanks